# How to read a fixed number of bytes?

Tags: go

```
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

package main

import (
  "io"
  "os"
  "log"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  buf := make([]byte, 4)
  for {
    n, err := io.ReadFull(os.Stdin, buf)
    fmt.Printf("== %d\n", n)
    if err == io.EOF {
      os.Stdout.Write(buf)
      os.Stdout.Write([]byte("\n"))
      break
    } else if err == nil {
      os.Stdout.Write(buf)
      os.Stdout.Write([]byte("\n"))
    } else {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying the above code. I am not sure why the last `io.ReadFull()` end up with the `log.Fatal(err)` branch. I thought it should read the `err == io.EOF` branch. Could anybody let me know who to read a fixed number of bytes until the end of the file? Thanks.

```
$ builtin printf %s {a..z} | go run main.go
== 4
abcd
== 4
efgh
== 4
ijkl
== 4
mnop
== 4
qrst
== 4
uvwx
== 2
2020/06/26 23:40:50 unexpected EOF
exit status 1
```

Comment: Read the docs. If it cannot read the required number of bytes, it returns io.ErrUnexpectedEOF, so you also have to check for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documention of `io.ReadFull`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull), it will attempt to read exactly `len(buf)` from the reader. As you've defined `buf` to be a slice of 4 bytes, `io.ReadFull` will try to read 4 bytes, and return an [`io.ErrUnexpectedEOF`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#pkg-variables) if an EOF is encountered during the read operation.

You can solve the problem by either using [`Reader.Read`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) (so `os.Stdin.Read()` in this case, as `os.Stdin` implements `io.Reader`), or by explicitly handling the `io.ErrUnexpectedEOF` error. `Reader.Read` will work as it attempts to read **at most** `len(buf)` instead of exactly `len(buf)`.